# oracle 19c : now rows selected while executing a select command

Tags: oracle

I was on the road to unlock HR user on oracle 19c. I started by connecting as SYS user and went to execute the sql query : SELECT name, con_id FROM v$pdbs;
I've expected to have PDB$SEED , ORCLPDB as results but the result was show,n is no rows selected.
ANY HELP!

Comment: Are you connected to the root CDB, a PDB, or a standalone DB? (I'm guessing the latter...)

Comment: I'm connected to the root CDB

Comment: Run the following: select CDB from v$database; and if the result is "no" then you are running a non-cdb installation.